# How to pass param value to require?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

In vuejs project, I want to create a function  which return a json data, the function has param booknumber and the param value is passed to require,
How can i achieve this

```
// something like below
function loadBook(booknumber){ 
  var item = require('/assets/book' + booknumber + '.json'); 
  return item; 
}

// call the function here
function clicked(){
  selectedBook = loadBook(12);
}
```

the above code will not work as the require does not accept dynamic value, is there any easy way to make it work ? thank u in advance

Comment: For what requirement are you sending param value to require? what are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: Please review the documentation if you want to use dynamic imports with Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

Comment: `require` does accept a dynamic value, see [require with expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) in the docs.